# SPI only returning zeros with Raspbian (It works with IoT core)

Tags: pi-3, python, spi, c++

I am using [this ADC](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads8341.pdf) connected to the channel 0 of my Pi3 board for reading values from a sensor. In IoT core, I was using a very simple code for testing the my device, and it worked fine. The C# code is the following:

```
// Initialize device
var settings = new SpiConnectionSettings(0);
settings.ClockFrequency = 1000000;
settings.Mode = SpiMode.Mode0;
// Get and intialize the SPI controller
var controller = await SpiController.GetDefaultAsync();
spi_dev = controller.GetDevice(settings);

// do stuff

byte[] read_buffer = new byte[3];
byte[] write_buffer = new byte[3] {0xDF, 0x00, 0x00 };
spi_dev.TransferFullDuplex(write_buffer, read_buffer);
```

---

Currrently, I'm trying to do the same in Raspbian, for comparing the performance. So far, I tried C/C++ libraries **wiringPi** and **bcm2835**, as well as Python library **SpiDev**.

I enabled the SPI connection using the raspi-config utility (I checked that */boot/config.txt* value *dtparam=spi=on* is uncommented). However, with any of the mentioned libraries, I always get zero as a response. The different scripts I am trying are the following:

Using **bcm2835**:

```
#include <bcm2835.h>
// ...
bcm2835_init();
bcm2835_spi_begin();
bcm2835_spi_setBitOrder(BCM2835_SPI_BIT_ORDER_MSBFIRST);
bcm2835_spi_setDataMode(BCM2835_SPI_MODE0);
// Clock of 1.5625MHz on RPI3 
bcm2835_spi_setClockDivider(BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_256);
bcm2835_spi_chipSelect(BCM2835_SPI_CS0);

bcm2835_spi_setChipSelectPolarity(BCM2835_SPI_CS0, LOW);

// Send the control byte to the slave and simultaneously read 3 bytes back.
char send_data[3] = {0xDF, 0x00, 0x00};
char read_data[3] = {0};
bcm2835_spi_transfernb(send_data, read_data, 3);
```

using **wiringPi**:

```
#include <wiringPiSPI.h>

int fd, result;
unsigned char buffer[100];

fd = wiringPiSPISetup(0, 1000000);

buffer[0] = 0xDF;
result = wiringPiSPIDataRW(0, buffer, 3);
```

and using **SpiDev**:

```
import spidev

#initialise SPIDev
spi=spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)
spi.max_speed_hz = 1000000

ctrl_byte = 0xDF
send = [ctrl_byte, 0x00, 0x00]
response = spi.xfer(send)
```

Comment: For some reason my comment asking for a photo has been deleted - not by me.  We need a photo of the connections if you want any help.

Answer (score 0):

Use BCM2835 "library" with great caution - "transfer" function does not read SPI slave data.

Comment: Could you provide a library, a function, or an example with which I can read back values from SPI?

Comment: Well, yes and no. I have been sidetracked for few months from my main C++ coding task and my code is not for public view anyway - too messy. Maybe in couple of months when the project is done - really sorry I cannot be of more help.